# `tar` slow  performance through `xargs`

Tags: shell, tar, xargs

Please consider this snippet:

`tar -Oxvf archive.tgz | grep something`

or this:

`tar tf archive.tgz > /tmp/x && tar -Oxvf archive.tgz -T /tmp/x | grep something`

versus this:

`tar tf archive.tgz | xargs -I{} tar -Oxvf archive.tgz {} | grep something`

First two snippets are very fast and similar, while third is ~40 times slower (this index is relative to archive contents I guess). Why is that?

Comment: It seems like when using `-T` switch, `tar` reads the list and extracts files in one pass under own rule (as i.e. it does not extract in order as in `/tmp/x` file list, but in order they are compressed), while when using `xargs`, penalty is taken from sequential execution. Even if this turns true it's too slow IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is your use of `-I{}` in xargs. The man page says:

```
   -I replace-str
```

> Replace  occurrences  of replace-str in the initial-arguments  with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not
>   terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.
>   **Implies -x and -L 1**.

The implied `-L 1` makes `xargs` run your `tar -Oxvf archive.tgz {}` once per file in the archive, rather than running tar once to extract all the files listed on xargs' stdin.

Simplified example of the difference:

```
$ (echo foo; echo bar)|xargs -I{} echo {}
foo
bar

$ (echo foo; echo bar)|xargs echo 
foo bar
```

Fixed:

```
tar tf archive.tgz | xargs tar -Oxvf archive.tgz | grep something
```

Note however that the output of this will not be the same as what you get using `xargs -I{}` if the file names given to `xargs` are not in tar file order (i.e. the same order that `tar t` lists them in). The `xargs -I{}` version will ouptut the files in the order you provided to xargs, whereas this version will output them in tar file order.

Comment: OK. This is certainly correct answer to asked question, but I want to comment that this way `tar tf archive.tgz | sort | xargs tar -Oxvf archive.tgz` wont sort files from archive when outputting, while `tar tf archive.tgz | sort | xargs -I{} tar -Oxvf archive.tgz {}` will sort, and time penalty is taken for the reason you explained. Thanks

Comment: @theta point taken - I actually considered putting a note about the potential ordering change in there, but decided against because `tar tf` will always to generate the same order as `tar x` extracts them. A bad decision in hindsight, since it's clearly a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat uncertain what you want to achive with your examples. I don't understand what the first pipe in the first example is supposed to achieve, since the output that gets piped to the second tar isn't used. A `&&` would seem a better way to join both commands (execute the second only if the first was successful). Apart from that, if you're using the complete list of files for extraction (and only for that task), as in your examples, it wouldn't be necessary to spend a separate tar run on creating it, since tar by default will extract all files, unless told otherwise.

As far as speed is concerned - the tar at the receiving end of the pipe has no special means to distinguish if the input it gets stems from another tar for optimization. What does make a difference though is, that in the case of two tar commands, the first will start its output immediately, and so the second tar can start running, while the xargs will gather all data first, and then start its output and feed the tar arranged to run after it.

If you're looking for a fast way to extract only a subset of files from a tar archive, and want to select by filename, I'd recommend using [star](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/star/star.1.html), which has a builtin find command.

Comment: Oops, you are right, I added `&&`. My problem was that I had files which were stored inside tar archive in unsorted order - that was the way they were created - and I needed output (grep) traversing through tar archive contents but in sorted order. It turned out that `tar` can't extract files differently then in order they were stored, as after all `tar` was designed as Tape ARchiver. As mentioned earlier `tar` doesn't respect order of files pointed in filelist (-T switch) either - it extracts in one pass and if file is anywhere in list it extracts

Comment: @theta it doesn't respect the ordering of multiple command line arguments either, they behave just like `-T`. The issue is `xargs -I{}` (see my answer)